# Convert all letters to uppercase in all text files from a directory

Tags: command-line, sed

I have a lot of text files (with .txt extension) in one directory in which I want to convert all letters to uppercase. How can I do this using the terminal?

I've tried:

```
sed -i 's/[A-Z]/[a-z]/g' *.txt
```

but without success...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The right way using `sed` should be done with the help of `\U` switch:

```bsh
sed -i 's/.*/\U&/' *.txt
```

See also:

- [Match text with regular expressions and transform upper and lower case letters with sed](http://giantdorks.org/alain/match-text-with-regular-expressions-and-transform-upper-and-lower-case-letters-with-sed/).
- [Different ways to capitalize the contents of a file](http://www.theunixschool.com/2012/03/different-ways-to-capitalize-contents.html).